# Too many httpd processes on my Cpanel VPS

Tags: performance, vps

For months my VPS has been doing fine. But since last week I saw Mysql server stopped two times and I was told that it was some load issue. I don't want to upgrade due to budget issue.

Yesterday when the VPS was slow and I found plenty of httpd processes. My sites get traffic of 2-3000 unique visitors a day.

I then checked /var/log/messages but couldn't find any useful information.

**So why all of sudden so my httpd processes?**

Then I rebooted it through WHM interface but again I saw the same number of processes. Then I restarted the VPS container. Then it was fine.

I've reduced Max Clients in the WHM/Apache Configurastion to 30.

Mine is OpenVZ VPS with 2 GB RAM with DSO PHP handler with Apache suEXEC and Ruid2 off

[image]

Comment: post your apache config.

Comment: @Mxx I've uploaded it here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hguTXC76P6HjDH9OsV1jEr3PYtRbAlZMaUy-5NWyYOc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to : http://community.mybb.com/thread-151383.html

My account was banned and was enabled after upgrade. But again the same problem.

I checked the URL's using Apache's mod_status and it showed me full of URL's to single webpage.

Yesterday I missed this clue by mistake that the raw access log of this site was around 80MB.

I'll paste a few lines of the access log here:

```
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:30 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?CQC=FYUPDPXN HTTP/1.1" 200 72415
> "http://engadget.search.aol.com/search?q=DLTVJFQD" "Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.1 (KHTML, like
> Gecko) Chrome/4.0.219.6 Safari/532.1"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:30 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?IQX=XHTIJX HTTP/1.1" 200 72413
> "http://www.google.com/?q=MOYKI" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 7.0;
> Windows NT 6.0; en-US)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:31 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?ZFWEMAQA=EAUPA HTTP/1.1" 200 72417
> "http://www.google.com/?q=BKUFDT" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.1;
> Windows XP)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:31 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?WWTJV=ZLMPL HTTP/1.1" 200 72414
> "http://forum.indiaconsumercomplaints.com/RBKQPZRUCT" "Mozilla/5.0
> (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090913
> Firefox/3.5.3"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:31 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?YSBHA=XTTTPDWKR HTTP/1.1" 200 72418
> "http://forum.indiaconsumercomplaints.com/OXTZIDPJ" "Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.1 (KHTML, like
> Gecko) Chrome/4.0.219.6 Safari/532.1"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:31 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?ATBWHKQA=OSHO HTTP/1.1" 200 72416
> "http://www.google.com/?q=QFAOIUH" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.1;
> Windows XP)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:31 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?RXZSAVQA=IJIVPLXELE HTTP/1.1" 200 72422
> "http://forum.indiaconsumercomplaints.com/ZBDFP" "Mozilla/4.0
> (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; SV1; .NET CLR
> 2.0.50727; InfoPath.2)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:31 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?ZPLNRNKX=QQWAHU HTTP/1.1" 200 72418
> "http://www.google.com/?q=CVGLTWZRV" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows
> NT 5.2; en-US; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824 Firefox/3.5.3 (.NET CLR
> 3.5.30729)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:31 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?FSS=QNQKIKZMZ HTTP/1.1" 200 72416
> "http://forum.indiaconsumercomplaints.com/CZWIJUGXGT" "Mozilla/4.0
> (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET
> CLR 2.0.50727; InfoPath.2)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:31 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?PJWUFQJXBN=KRRJOJSH HTTP/1.1" 200 72422
> "http://forum.indiaconsumercomplaints.com/QAOLBB" "Mozilla/4.0
> (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET
> CLR 2.0.50727; InfoPath.2)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:31 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?ZOS=KPTQHMZ HTTP/1.1" 200 72414
> "http://www.google.com/?q=QIZQWPAY" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE
> 6.1; Windows XP)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:31 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?UDU=QKTJLBB HTTP/1.1" 200 72414
> "http://www.usatoday.com/search/results?q=DPIDLBQOTY" "Mozilla/4.0
> (compatible; MSIE 6.1; Windows XP)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:31 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?IQX=VWIALDZF HTTP/1.1" 200 72415
> "http://www.google.com/?q=WVPKEHFU" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE
> 6.1; Windows XP)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:31 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?HKEJTWMZ=TXGWFEEVY HTTP/1.1" 200 72421
> "http://forum.indiaconsumercomplaints.com/SEJDGR" "Opera/9.80 (Windows
> NT 5.2; U; ru) Presto/2.5.22 Version/10.51"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:31 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?TEBIS=GVTEM HTTP/1.1" 200 72414
> "http://engadget.search.aol.com/search?q=TIZBOS" "Mozilla/4.0
> (compatible; MSIE 6.1; Windows XP)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:31 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?XYP=NECRI HTTP/1.1" 200 72412
> "http://www.google.com/?q=FYWDCYG" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64;
> en-US; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090913 Firefox/3.5.3"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:31 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?WUXDZO=XHAIVL HTTP/1.1" 200 72416
> "http://forum.indiaconsumercomplaints.com/URJYX" "Mozilla/4.0
> (compatible; MSIE 6.1; Windows XP)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:32 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?HLVI=DLBTIN HTTP/1.1" 200 72414
> "http://www.usatoday.com/search/results?q=QXLDQM" "Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.2; en-US; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824
> Firefox/3.5.3 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:31 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?NHVLQEX=OJQD HTTP/1.1" 200 72415
> "http://forum.indiaconsumercomplaints.com/HPQDQXNTO" "Mozilla/4.0
> (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.2; Win64; x64; Trident/4.0)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:32 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?IBNZSBYFB=DVIUQUOPFZ HTTP/1.1" 200 72423
> "http://www.usatoday.com/search/results?q=WZNWRF" "Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824
> Firefox/3.5.3 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:32 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?BOU=YRWWZ HTTP/1.1" 200 72412
> "http://www.usatoday.com/search/results?q=ECCXJBGZ" "Mozilla/4.0
> (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; SV1; .NET CLR
> 2.0.50727; InfoPath.2)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:32 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?VUKWMEBKHY=EIAPSYM HTTP/1.1" 200 72421
> "http://engadget.search.aol.com/search?q=EJLHAG" "Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824
> Firefox/3.5.3 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:32 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?NZX=FIX HTTP/1.1" 200 72410
> "http://www.usatoday.com/search/results?q=VRESMQPO" "Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824
> Firefox/3.5.3 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:32 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?DBC=AJMHKMJ HTTP/1.1" 200 72414
> "http://engadget.search.aol.com/search?q=UVBBXJTN" "Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824
> Firefox/3.5.3 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:32 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?VFEQTNQCOQ=ZVJHRPXSE HTTP/1.1" 200 72423
> "http://www.google.com/?q=JVEJJT" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0;
> Windows NT 5.2; Win64; x64; Trident/4.0)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:32 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?VGWHSY=PTOREJ HTTP/1.1" 200 72416
> "http://engadget.search.aol.com/search?q=EOVMCAPVKP" "Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824
> Firefox/3.5.3 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:32 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?SAFNO=MLHYOLSO HTTP/1.1" 200 72417
> "http://forum.indiaconsumercomplaints.com/PMSNINVZ" "Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824
> Firefox/3.5.3 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:32 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?BYXZWHZMPS=DQL HTTP/1.1" 200 72417
> "http://www.usatoday.com/search/results?q=YLAGFTGMHN" "Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.1 (KHTML, like
> Gecko) Chrome/4.0.219.6 Safari/532.1"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:32 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?JDWAJLOTF=LNAYQZV HTTP/1.1" 200 72420
> "http://www.google.com/?q=HSXQOL" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT
> 5.2; en-US; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824 Firefox/3.5.3 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:32 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?QAF=VJDOPRBCC HTTP/1.1" 200 72416
> "http://www.usatoday.com/search/results?q=POXVZUHJY" "Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824
> Firefox/3.5.3 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:32 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?RHTT=JIJT HTTP/1.1" 200 72412
> "http://engadget.search.aol.com/search?q=JLYMG" "Mozilla/4.0
> (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR
> 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:32 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?NGNRMXKJ=WGX HTTP/1.1" 200 72415
> "http://engadget.search.aol.com/search?q=YPATNP" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U;
> Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090913 Firefox/3.5.3"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:32 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?CPQHR=TTHN HTTP/1.1" 200 72413
> "http://www.usatoday.com/search/results?q=TTFRCH" "Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows; U; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; en-US)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:32 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?GLEQZOIH=ZFPNKWYW HTTP/1.1" 200 72420
> "http://engadget.search.aol.com/search?q=QGHCVDB" "Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.2; en-US; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824
> Firefox/3.5.3 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:32 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?QHJSJ=UZGOYYOB HTTP/1.1" 200 72417
> "http://engadget.search.aol.com/search?q=HINAER" "Opera/9.80 (Windows
> NT 5.2; U; ru) Presto/2.5.22 Version/10.51"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:32 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?SVNREOGG=MBVUL HTTP/1.1" 200 72417
> "http://engadget.search.aol.com/search?q=IMCXJR" "Mozilla/4.0
> (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET
> CLR 2.0.50727; InfoPath.2)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:32 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?MNMHOPTVA=JJILFTGXG HTTP/1.1" 200 72422
> "http://engadget.search.aol.com/search?q=ISFMMWOOFW" "Mozilla/4.0
> (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; SV1; .NET CLR
> 2.0.50727; InfoPath.2)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:32 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?HITDWFGZDQ=YWS HTTP/1.1" 200 72417
> "http://engadget.search.aol.com/search?q=CLTHOPM" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11;
> U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090913 Firefox/3.5.3"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:32 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?EXVMPL=GFMZHSMD HTTP/1.1" 200 72418
> "http://engadget.search.aol.com/search?q=URPZSYBEIG" "Mozilla/4.0
> (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET
> CLR 2.0.50727; InfoPath.2)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:33 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?IJQDNJHQDE=RWFEYMEBY HTTP/1.1" 200 72423
> "http://www.usatoday.com/search/results?q=ZSNKRDHZ" "Opera/9.80
> (Windows NT 5.2; U; ru) Presto/2.5.22 Version/10.51"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:33 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?FILLDSZY=FXGNXBG HTTP/1.1" 200 72419
> "http://forum.indiaconsumercomplaints.com/LVTZGDO" "Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.1) Gecko/20090718
> Firefox/3.5.1"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:33 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?PIS=VRBUB HTTP/1.1" 200 72412
> "http://www.google.com/?q=FGZNJ" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64;
> en-US; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090913 Firefox/3.5.3"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:33 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?QRXEPOB=DCQC HTTP/1.1" 200 72415
> "http://engadget.search.aol.com/search?q=GQFZYWMXMB" "Mozilla/4.0
> (compatible; MSIE 6.1; Windows XP)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:33 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?IVWLDGMIQ=AYBC HTTP/1.1" 200 72417
> "http://forum.indiaconsumercomplaints.com/ILBLYE" "Mozilla/4.0
> (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET
> CLR 2.0.50727; InfoPath.2)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:33 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?ZSRMYIYA=TZHD HTTP/1.1" 200 72416
> "http://forum.indiaconsumercomplaints.com/YKHBLHGDQP" "Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.2; en-US; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824
> Firefox/3.5.3 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:33 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?GEF=ZAKJVYCRJ HTTP/1.1" 200 72416
> "http://engadget.search.aol.com/search?q=JZZMTYFQ" "Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.1) Gecko/20090718
> Firefox/3.5.1"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:33 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?PVMLS=ULBHQ HTTP/1.1" 200 72414
> "http://engadget.search.aol.com/search?q=HKKUQ" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows;
> U; Windows NT 5.2; en-US; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824 Firefox/3.5.3
> (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:33 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?MXQCULQWH=BLSGGFIA HTTP/1.1" 200 72421
> "http://www.usatoday.com/search/results?q=LHRWG" "Mozilla/4.0
> (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET
> CLR 2.0.50727; InfoPath.2)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:33 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?OCC=NPYGRGSWEY HTTP/1.1" 200 72417
> "http://www.usatoday.com/search/results?q=JCINPDCWX" "Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.1 (KHTML, like
> Gecko) Chrome/4.0.219.6 Safari/532.1"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:33 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?PBCZXKC=QCLKPWVBQ HTTP/1.1" 200 72420
> "http://forum.indiaconsumercomplaints.com/RXUVEL" "Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows; U; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; en-US)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:33 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?DMX=KTRKR HTTP/1.1" 200 72412
> "http://engadget.search.aol.com/search?q=VJUARQVZ" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11;
> U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090913 Firefox/3.5.3"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:33 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?CQKMQIQ=OFITSH HTTP/1.1" 200 72417
> "http://www.usatoday.com/search/results?q=SQDSRWJYH" "Opera/9.80
> (Windows NT 5.2; U; ru) Presto/2.5.22 Version/10.51"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:33 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?EIHL=ZNGZPR HTTP/1.1" 200 72414
> "http://forum.indiaconsumercomplaints.com/DPBQGTFG" "Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824
> Firefox/3.5.3 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:33 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?ZASJNRZ=SRWSHR HTTP/1.1" 200 72417
> "http://forum.indiaconsumercomplaints.com/BAGLSUQJPM" "Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows; U; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; en-US)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:33 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?MQYHVR=ATWFHROM HTTP/1.1" 200 72418
> "http://www.google.com/?q=ESJMXXYD" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE
> 6.1; Windows XP)"
> 50.23.129.218 - - [22/Feb/2014:21:13:33 +0530] "GET /Thread-Airwil-Intellicity?CHQLI=EPMNZQJS HTTP/1.1" 200 72417
> "http://www.google.com/?q=NECHGBXCD" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Wi
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to lower your serverlimit & maxclients to a number your server can handle. To simplify, you can set the same # for both serverlimit & maxclients. Amount of memory each child uses * X should not exceed your total ram, where X is the setting for them. Generalizing, with 2GB, that should be like 20.

A setting of serverlimit/maxclients too high for the system makes apapche unstable. While it  ran fine under light load, once you got heavy load, your high settings built yourself a queue that is beyond your ability to push. This results slow runtime as now need to server both your queue and new requests that are coming in. And then you'll also be hitting swap which makes everything go ultra slow and further causes spiral into doom.

Answer (score 0):

If Cpanel does not provide such a functionality built in, consider using a tool such as [`check-httpd-limits`](https://code.google.com/p/check-httpd-limits/) or similar to calculate appropriate settings for your running Apache config. It will measure your server's memory, your Apache's memory usage and approximate load and recommend best settings so that your Apache is not over or under configured. It also has some settings to measure Apache over multiple runs/days to make it a bit more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

We can't really help you with [capacity planning](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning) but you may be able to get some pointers about capacity management.

> Mysql server stopped two times

It is very unlikely that MySQL just stopped - and even then that's not a meaningful description of why it ceased to function. More likely the daemon was killed by OOM or crashed. There are several things that might have happenned - exactly what did happen is recorded in your log files.

First thing to do is man-up and stop using cpanel for your configuration - such tools can be useful for handling mundane admin tasks but they hide a lot of what's really happening in your system. We need to know how your server is configured. Next you might want to spend some time learning how to manage your applications - go get some good books and spend time on the internet - there's lots of documentation out there.

> I found plenty of httpd processes

Not a meaningful metric.

> My sites get traffic of 2-3000 unique visitors a day.

Also not a meaningful metric

There are a large number of httpd's in the run queue - there's lots of reasons why that may be the case. Limiting the number of connections/processes/clients will avoid the problem by blocking connections from your users - do you want to provide a good service or keep your system stats sweet?

There is a lot which can be done to improve the performance and throughput of a system (if each requests takes less time then there will be fewer requests in progress at any one time, hence lower CPU and memory demands) - but that needs time, investigation and the skills of someone who knows what they are doing - not a question and some answers on serverfault.com. Alternatively you could just buy more hardware - the screenshot suggests you need around ten times the current capacity (although it may be significantly less depending on the nature of the current performance crisis) - hence hiring a competent HTTP performance expert for a couple of weeks may prove cheaper.